# Topology of Analytic Number Theory

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am really interested in the arts of topology and analytic number theory, so I naturally acquired interest in the potential connections between them.  Unlike the algebraic number theory and ongoing arithmetic topology, it seems that topology did not find much application to problems in analytic number theory, say distribution of primes, additive properties, etc.  Only interesting paper I found is Furstenburg’s proof of the infinitude of primes using topological arguments, but that was from early 1950.

So my question is that do you know any interesting connection between topology and analytic number theory?  Do the set of all primes or natural numbers exhibit some interesting topology (definitely not discrete topology)?

Comment: @reuns could you provide me references to learn about them?

Comment: Elliptic curves & modular forms have many topological geometrical parts, same for (adelic) automorphic forms. Since you mention the prime number theorem you may search for the L-functions (Euler products) defined from those objects.

Comment: As reuns says, the adèles (and idèles) are the outcome of trying to understand number theory using functional analysis. Their topology encodes important representation theoretical data of number fields, which can be used to prove results in class field theory. I think Tate's thesis is a good place to start.